# Install PIP while non-root user gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: apache-http-server, python, pip, python3

I am trying to install PIP on a server which I do not have root access. I managed to download `get-pip.py` using `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

Though when I try to run the following: `python get-pip.py --user`, I receive the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Some research showed me that I am missing a specific library named `libffi`, though I am unable to install it because I do not have root access.

Another article suggested that I configure `--without-ensurepip`, however, I do not know how to go about doing this. Could someone please explain what it means to "configure"?

I am running python 3.7 on an Apache, Bluehost server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
mkdir ~/src
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.7.2.tgz
cd Python-3.7.2
./configure --without-ensurepip --prefix=$HOME/.local \
    LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/.local/lib64" CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/.local/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include"
make
make install
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1534210/1672723#11301911) (by [zzart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758202/zzart))
to [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I assume that that ```./configure``` command is one (long) command.  Please be careful when you copy-and-paste from the terminal; lines longer than 80 characters (i.e., the width of the terminal window) will often be pasted as multiple, separate lines.